# Limit of a sequence with $a_{1}=2, a_{n+1}=\frac{n^{2}-1}{a_{n}}+2$ for $n\geq1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following sequence: $$(a_{n})_{n\geq1}; a_{1}=2, a_{n+1}=\frac{n^{2}-1}{a_{n}}+2, n\geq1$$

At first exercise calculated the limit of $\frac{a_n}{n}$.I used $n\leq a_n\leq n+1$ and I got the limit $1.$

At the last two exercises I need to calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{3}_{k}}{n^{4}}$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k}_{k}}{n^{n+1}}$$

I tried to use again the first inequality but I got the limit $\infty$.How to start?

Comment: In my book, it's $n^{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

You certainly do not get infinity for neither of the limits.

Since $1\leq \frac{a_n}{n}\leq 1+\frac{1}{n}$, you have
$$k^3\leq a_k^3\leq k^3(1+\frac{1}{k})^3=(k+1)^3$$
hence
$$\frac{1}{4} n^2 (1 + n)^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3\leq\sum_{k=1}^na_k^3\leq\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)^3=\frac{1}{4} (12 n + 13 n^2 + 6 n^3 + n^4)$$
so that the sum is sandwiched between two polynomials of $n$ of degree $4$, with leading coefficient $\frac{1}{4}$. Hence the first limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.

For the second limit, we have
$$k^k\leq a_k^k\leq k^k(1+\frac{1}{k})^k=(k+1)^k$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^k\leq\sum_{k=1}^na_k^k\leq\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)^k$$
The r.h.s is bounded above by $n(n+1)^n < (n+1)^{(n+1)}$, so the second limit, if it exists, is at most $e$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.At the second limit, in my book the right answer is 0.